# How these two references point to the same Object in the heap?

Tags: java

Could anyone explain how these two references will point to same object in the heap?

```
String strA = new String("APPLES");
String strB = new String("APPLES");
```

Comment: Who told you that they are pointing to the same object on the heap?. does `strA==strB` return `true`?. `equals()` compares values of Strings, not references. Please show us how you tried to *compare* the 2 references.

Comment: you are creating a **new String();** how could they'll be equal?

Comment: what do you mean by `Two reference will point to same object`? Both are different objects here.

Comment: For this case In the heap,How many objects will be created?

Comment: How Can I see How Many Objects created for myClass in java.

Comment: Store instance on instantiation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes java will use the same heap space when it detects the same String.

You can clearly see this in **byteCode**

```
 public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
Code:
      0: new           #21                 // class java/lang/String
      3: dup
      4: ldc           #23                 // String APPLES
      6: invokespecial #25                 // Method java/lang/String."<init>":
Ljava/lang/String;)V
      9: astore_1
     10: new           #21                 // class java/lang/String
     13: dup
     14: ldc           #23                 // String APPLES
     16: invokespecial #25                 // Method java/lang/String."<init>":
Ljava/lang/String;)V
     19: astore_2
     20: getstatic     #28                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/
o/PrintStream;
     23: invokevirtual #34                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.printl
:()V
     26: return
```

As you can see `#23` is used for the both object which mean they are located on the same memory location.

Now lets look on different string

```
String strA = new String("APPLES");
String strB = new String("BANANA");
```

The byteCode for this is:

```
 public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
   Code:
      0: new           #21                 // class java/lang/String
      3: dup
      4: ldc           #23                 // String APPLES
      6: invokespecial #25                 // Method java/lang/String."<init>":
Ljava/lang/String;)V
      9: astore_1
     10: new           #21                 // class java/lang/String
     13: dup
     14: ldc           #28                 // String BANANA
     16: invokespecial #25                 // Method java/lang/String."<init>":
Ljava/lang/String;)V
     19: astore_2
     20: return
```

Now `BANANA` will be located on different memory location as seen in the byteCode above. That is because Java now knows that it differs from `APPLES` that it need to be located/stored on a different memory location.

Comment: My confusion is both will create single object or different object.

Comment: @user3920792 of course on different object. if they point on the same object when one changes its String the other will get changed as well

Comment: As you can see #23 is used for the both object which mean they are located on the same memory location. whts the meaning please explain

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin -  *Yes java will use the same heap space when it detects the same String.* ?. Please re-phrase this line and explicitly mention *same String in the String pool*. As The OP might get confused with String Objects and String Pool constants. #23 is the String constant (read from pool the second time around)

Comment: @user3920792 - In your code, you are creating a total of `3` Objects. `"APPLES"` is created only once and placed in the *String Pool*, Then `strA` and `strB` are created as 2 *seperate* objects on the heap.

Comment: @TheLostMind  How Can I see How Many Objects created for myClass in java.

Comment: @user3920792 - Well.. The simplest way would be to compare the *IdentityHashCodes* of `"APPLES"`, `strA` and `strB`.

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely experiencing string interning

> [3.10.5. String Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5)
>
> Moreover, a string literal always refers to the same instance of class String. This is because string literals - or, more generally, strings that are the values of constant expressions (§15.28) - are "interned" so as to share unique instances, using the method String.intern.

There's also the method [`String.intern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

```
String strA = new String("APPLES");
String strB = new String("APPLES");
System.out.println(strA.equals(strB));
System.out.println(strA == strB);
```

Result:

```
true
false
```

The Strings are the same because all of their characters match, but they are not the same INSTANCE. They are totally different objects bearing the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the new String variables do not point to the same object on the heap. Since you are using the new operator it will almost always allocate the object on the heap. Since you are using it twice it will create two different objects. Rod_Algonquin and Patrick are partially correct in their answers in that the String Literal "APPLES" do point to the same object but that object is passed to the String constructor. The two variables do not point to the same object as the String Literal "APPLES". All strings known at compile time are all interned at run time to save space. But any string created using new will not point to the same object as a literal unless you use String.intern.

Edit: Although a very aggressive JVM could potentially optimize such cases as this to make all references point to the same object, but to my knowledge no current JVM does this for any String created using new. It does seem like a pointless optimization that a JVM would do as it doesn't add much benefit and a programmer can detect such cases much easier than a JVM can.

Comment: It wouldn't just be pointless, but indeed change the semantics and thus be *simply wrong*. By definition, the `new` operator creates a *new* object, meaning that the `==` operator may ***never ever*** return `true` when applied to two different variables, each separately instantiated with `new`.

Comment: Although String could be considered a special case. With all of the rule bending they already have done with Strings, such as allowing the use of the + operator. This is a pointless discussion as I don't think any JVM author will actually implement any such idea.